# Yammer ID from Email (Wordpress PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, yammer

I'm trying to get the yammer ID of a user based on an email address, I wrote this

```
$emailx="email@email.com";

function get_yammer_id($email){
$url = 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/by_email.json';
$response = wp_remote_get( $url, array(
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array( 'Host' => 'www.yammer.com', 'Authorization' => 'Bearer ********-**********************' ),
    'body' => array( 'email' => $email),
    'cookies' => array()
 )
);
$return = $response;
return $return;
}

$result = get_yammer_id($emailx);
echo $result;
```

The last echo greets me with "Array" though.
If I try to swap it for

```
echo $result[0];
```

I'll get nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: what are print if you make a **var_dump($result);** ?

Comment: A whole lot of text, here is the interesting part
`["body"]=> string(1447) "[{"type":"user","id":***************,"network_id":************,"state":"active","guid":null,"job_title":"","location":null,"interests":null,"summary":null,"expertise":null,"full_name":"******************","activated_at":"2018/07/04 11:44:23 +0000","auto_activated":false,"show_ask_for_photo":true,"first_name":"*******","last_name":"**************","network_name":"*********************************","network_domains":[],"url":"https://www.yammer.com/`

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution but I found one

```
$emailx="email@email.com";

function get_yammer_id($email){
$url = 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/by_email.json';
$response = wp_remote_get( $url, array(
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array( 'Host' => 'www.yammer.com', 'Authorization' => 'Bearer *******-*********************' ),
    'body' => array( 'email' => $email),
    'cookies' => array()
 )
);
$return = (explode(",",$response['body']));
return (int)str_replace('"id":', '', $return[1]);
}

$result = get_yammer_id($emailx);
echo $result;
```

Does anyone have a better one?